# How to "warm start" a deep link visit through adb

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am writing a service that opens deep links to Android apps through adb like so:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.example.com/deeplinktest com.example.mjohnst.deeplinktest
```

The above command works correctly:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.example.com/... pkg=com.example.mjohnst.deeplinktest }
Status: ok
Activity: com.example.mjohnst.deeplinktest/.MainActivity
ThisTime: 606
TotalTime: 606
WaitTime: 731
Complete
```

What I want to do, is have the app already open/warm to *any* view, and still be able to visit the deep link.

If I have the app open on the emulator and try this, I  get this warning:

```
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

and the deep link is not visited (the current, non-linked view of the app is brought to the foreground).

**Is there any way for me to visit a deep link on an already open app *through adb or another interface?***

**EDIT:** I know that there's a `-s` flag to kill the app before visiting, but this is not what I want. I would like the warm start to provide a performance gain

Comment: Is your `MainActivity` configured as `singleTop` or `singleTask` (or even `singleInstance`) by any chance? If so, the intent fired through `adb` may be received in [`onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29). The warning indicates that no new activity was spawned because an instance already existed in the back stack and was thus brought to front. Hence, the activity does not go through `onCreate()` (and doesn't receive the intent there), but rather gets it in the aforementioned method.

Comment: I have not modified `android:launchMode` in my `<activity>`. It should be using `standard` mode. That is interesting insight though... I'll look into testing other `launchModes` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that if you start the app via a non-deeplink activity, deep linking "warm" will work.

Used this adb command to start the app:

`shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n {packageName}/{activityName}`